# PHPUnitTest does not connect to Test-DB in Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I want to implement some small calculation tests in my project and set up a test database (`symfony_tests`) with only a few entries but the same structure as the main one.

According to the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html#changing-database-settings-for-functional-tests), I can use the test db with PHPUnit like this:

*phpunit.xml.dist*

```
...
<php>
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
    <env name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="AppKernel" />
    <env name="DATABASE_URL" value="mysql://username:password@localhost/symfony_tests" />
</php>
...
```

However, when running `phpunit` it still connects to the main database and fails. When I update the db in `parameters.yml` to the test db it succeeds.

Is this the best practice for db entry testing (if not what is) and where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

One of your tests is probably trying to execute Symfony code that wants to setup a database connection. To make sure Symfony (or rather, Doctrine) also uses the correct database in test mode, add this to your `app/config/config_test.yml` file:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    dbname: symfony_tests
```

That should make any connections that are run through your tests connect to the proper database.

Note that the link you posted is for Symfony 4. The [Symfony 3.x docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/testing/database.html#changing-database-settings-for-functional-tests) on this subject also mention the above approach.